# Create an instance of a derived class using static method of base class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, static-methods

Regarding the following model, how can I write method `Make` to fulfill the 
usage purpose?

**Note:**
I don't want to repeat `Make` method in every derived class.

**Usage:**

```
Derived instance = Drived.Make();
AnotherDerived instance = AnotherDrived.Make();
ThirdDerived instance = ThirdDrived.Make();
```

**Model:**

```
class Base
{
   public static Base Make()
   {
       // What to write here?
   }
}

class Derived : Base
{
}

class AnotherDerived : Base
{
}

class ThirdDerived : Base
{
}
```

Comment: ??? = `return new Derived();`. Please clarify your question. What's your intent?

Comment: @usr Would you please let me complete the question before down-voting?

Comment: Maybe before posting the question, you should complete it (though I didn't downvote).

Comment: I didn't downvote. I'm trying to find out what you want to achieve so that I can give you what you need. There is no obvious answer to the first version of the question.

Comment: I'm guessing you'd want an abstract factory pattern here.

Comment: I love people who instead of focusing on the problem try to change the whole question

Comment: Hans, I know about a dozen ways to achieve what you asked literally. How am I supposed to pick without knowing what your goals are? Don't give up. Reply to what people are asking. The questions are being asked for a reason (which might not be obvious to you).

Comment: @Hans What you're doing looks alot like the [factory pattern](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Answer (score 4):

Static methods aren't inherited. Syntactically, they look they are, but when it's compiled, the base class method is being called directly. You'd have to have some way in the base class to indicate what type you want to create. I'm thinking that would be done by either using generics on the method (as is suggested in another answer) or on the class itself:

```
class Base<T> where T : new()
{
    public static T Make()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}

class Derived : Base<Derived>
{
}

class AnotherDerived : Base<AnotherDerived>
{
}

class ThirdDerived : Base<ThirdDerived>
{
}
```

Comment: I was also thinking of this solution. With this solution, `var instance = ThirdDerived.Make();` would be a strongly typed `ThirdDerived` instance. This is not because the `static` method is "modified" in the derived class. The syntax `ThirdDerived.Make()` is seen by the compiler as `Base<ThirdDerived>.Make()` (because the base class of `ThirdDerived` is `Base<ThirdDerived>`).

Comment: T could be a Base<T>, at least it seems so at this point with latest C#? Then you can call Derived.Make as long as Derived:Base<Derived> (i.e. all derived classes have to be sort of self-referential for the base static method to work).

Answer (score 3):

You would write it as:

```
class Derived : Base
{
   public static Derived Make()
   {
       ???
   }
}
```

It's irrelevant that Base has a `Make` method, they are both static so have no relation to each other.

Comment: I don't want to repeat Make in every derived class

Comment: @Hans why do you need Make? Use `new`.

Comment: static classes aren't inherited so you'd have to repeat it in every class.  Are you just trying to build a factory?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern.

Comment: @shf301 This is not a static class. Make is a static method

Comment: `static` methods are inherited in a sense. You can call them as `Derived.Make()` (or from inside `Derived` type as just `Make()`), but the compiler just translates the syntax to a `Base.Make()` call. Because of this kind of inheritance, your method _hides_ the original method. You need the `new` modifier, for example `public new static Derived Make()`. But this approach has a smell to it (all uses of `new` modifiers do).

Answer (score 3):

Despite all the good solutions people gave, I came to this conclusion that this is not possible. The source of my question is misunderstanding how static methods work on derived classes. I just found out that `Derived.Make()` is immediately compiled to `Base.Make()` hence `Base` never knows on what type `Make` was called. `Derived.Make()` is just a shortcut.

Comment: There you go. Glad your problem is solved (kind of). All existing answers are guessing answers that are now obsolete. That's why I ask for details *before* answering. I hope you get where I'm coming from.

Comment: You are absolutely right. There is one trick you can do if you are OK with `Base` being a generic type (["curiously recurring" pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)). See bcwhims's answer.

Answer (score 2):

To have only one method, you could use a generic method:

```
class Base
{
   public static T Make<T>() where T : Base
   {
       if (typeof(T) == typeof(Derived)) 
       {
            return (T)(object)new Derived();
       }
       // obviously more cases in here. just for illustration.
       else
       {
            return null;
       }
   }
}
```

then you'd have to call it as

```
Derived d = Base.Make<Derived>();
```

There's no option to write one method in the base class and have `Derived.Make` and `AnotherDerived.Make` do something else (moreover return different types as your example does) unless you consider code generation an option. Those are not different methods under the hood. They act as aliases to `Base.Make` unless you define a new method in each derived class.

Comment: If I look at a codebase and see a `Base.Make<Derived>`, i'd be like O_o.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Not my favorite pattern either, but more so because I consider it an abuse of generics. `Make<T>` can't really make any type T. It can only a make a few types that I've hard coded, which then needs to be documented. If it can restrict who inherits from Base then why wouldn't I just put a method in each derived class, since they are under my control.

Comment: @mike.z I'm with you on that. The intention of making this kind of `Make` method is still unclear to me from the OP's question. What is it he's actually trying to achieve.

Comment: You wouldn't have to restrict to certain types. You could change the where to `where T : Base, new()` and change the method to `return new T();`

Comment: @bcwhims If we do that, why do we need Make when we have a perfectly good thing for creating stuff: `new`? We could also use `Activator.CreateInstance` with some convention for constructors, again it needs some documenting.

Comment: We don't. It doesn't serve any logical purpose. I just trying to minimize class-specific code, which I assumed was the ultimate goal of this.

Comment: Code like `if (typeof(T) == typeof(Derived)) 
       {
            return (T)(object)new Derived();
       }` defies the purpose of generics.

Comment: Is this a good pattern anyway? It seems like a base class needs to know how to create a derived class. This looks weird...

Answer (score 0):

You can define conversion constructors for each derived class and use make like this: (Derived)Derived.Make();

Comment: Repeating Make in every derived class is not an option

Comment: Make would only be in the base class, you only define conversion constructors in every derived class.